# Determine percentage by selecting rows that contains a specific word

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have the following data:

```
Year  score count
2012 20 grade 2000
2005 20 grade 32
2005 40 grade 428 
2006 60 grade 731
2006 60 grade 472
...
```

I would need to know what percentage of occasions when the score is 60 grade does it lead to a good score.

I should assume the word grade appears in the text the word grade (so in this case 60 grade). 
My expected output would be the percentage of rows with only 60 grade based on counts.

How can I select this information by looking at values with 60 grade in Score and determine the percentage?

Comment: You have given 4 columns of data, but only three column names.  Also, you might want to show the expected output from your query.

Comment: No, they are three columns. 20 grade, 40 grade are in score column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a condition aggregation

```
select count(*)
 , sum(case when score like '60%' then 1 else 0  end)  num_x_60
 , (sum(case when score like '60%' then 1 else 0 ) / count(*))*100 perc
from my_table
```

Comment: To avoid a result of 0 (based on integer division) this should multiply first, then divide. Additionally you can use the alias : `100.0 * num_x_60 / count(*)`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `avg()` for the percentage:

```
select avg(case when score like '60%' then 100.0 else 0 end) as percentage
from my_table
```